# Putting a shadow in a round button

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I need some help how can I put a shadow on my round button. Here is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#e51c23" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="56dip"
            android:bottomRightRadius="56dip"
            android:topLeftRadius="56dip"
            android:topRightRadius="56dip" />


    </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp">  <!-- shadow effect -->
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#888888" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp">  <!-- Button Shape -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#55fff000"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            <padding android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="3px" 
                android:color="@color/border_pink" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```